shmat pointers with arrays of structures and another unrelated variable
Basically - I want to put a singular int, and an array of the following structures:
struct My_structure {
    char my_text[200];
    char my_name[20];
    int my_number;
};

Into a shared memory segment (IPC System V) obtained through shmat. However, I don't quite have an idea how to achieve that.
First of all, is it even possible to have the unrelated int and the array in one segment, or would I have to separate them? How would this separation work? shmget and shmat one time more just for that int?
Second - how to actually write it with shmat so I can handle errors? I've seen some examples of people using shmat with char (but no error handling) and with int (with error handling), but a struct obviously can't be in the negatives (the links below are what I saw).
https://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/shm/shmat.html
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ipc-shared-memory/
In the current state of the code, I get a warning for trying to compare a pointer and integer:
warning: comparison between pointer and integer
   55 |         if ((shm_pointer = (struct My_structure *) shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0)) == -1){
      | 

Third - how to make the "insides" of the shared memory an array? Or really anything that'd function similarly enough to an array, I need to be able to do array[number] in some shape or form.
Below is a snippet of code relevant to the question:

//those two lines before the problematic one seem to work right
//im pretty sure i wouldnt declare the array beforehand in the final version, its just more practical at this stage of writing the code
if ((key = ftok(argv[1],2137)) == -1){/*error handling*/}
if ((shm_id = shmget(key, sizeof(array_of_structs) + sizeof(unrelated_singular_int), 0644 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1){/*error handling*/}

//cant quite wrap my head around it
if ((shm_pointer = (struct My_structure *) shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0)) == -1){/*error handling*/}


For your immediate error, shmat returns a void * pointer. On error, it returns -1. But, more correctly, it returns (void *) -1 [similar to mmap]. So, the correct test is: if ((shm_pointer = shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0)) == (void *) -1) For cleanliness, you could create a define, similar to what mmap has: MAP_FAILED. (e.g.) #define SHMAT_FAILED ((void *) -1) and then: shm_pointer = shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0); if (shm_pointer == SHMAT_FAILED) Using two statements makes adding a breakpoint easier. BTW, because shmat returns a void *, there is no need to cast the return value.


(shm_pointer = (struct My_structure *) shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0)) is a pointer of type void *. You compare it with integer -1. You should compare with (void *)-1


I would use flexible array members and create an additional structure with int and needed array (99 in example is just an example):


struct My_structure {
    char my_text[200];
    char my_name[20];
    int my_number;
};

typedef struct
{
    int some_int;
    struct My_structure mystructarray[];
}My_data;


int getSHM_ID(size_t array_size)
{
    return  shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 
              sizeof(My_data) + array_size * sizeof((My_data){0}.mystructarray[0]), 
              IPC_CREAT | 0666);
}

void foo()
{
    int shm_id = getSHM_ID(99);
    if(shm_id != -1)
    {
        My_data *data;
        if((data = shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0)) != (void *)-1)
        {
            data->mystructarray[5] = (struct My_structure){"Hello", "world", 100};
            data->some_int = 500;
            /* .... */
        }
    }
}

Note:
Do not canst void * pointers as you might silence some important warnings. If the code will not compile - compile it with the C not C++ compiler

To be idiomatic, x -> y should be x->y
